# Как распаковать файл на стороне веб приложения?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Передаю со стороны сервера массив состоящий из двух объектов. Как правильно его разбить на два отдельных на стороне веба?

принимаю на стороне веба:

```
fetch('/relocate',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'                 
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(currentElem)                
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => console.log("json", json))
                    // .then(json => console.log("firstWindow",json[0].table))
                    // .then(json => console.log("secondWindow",json[1].table))  
                    .then(json =>this.$emit("newvalueforbothwindows", json)) 
        },
```

серверная часть

```
router.post('/relocate', (req, res) =>{
    console.log("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
    const fs = require("fs-extra");
    let body = "";

    req.on("data", function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    
    req.on("end", function(currentData) {
        currentData = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log('дата',currentData);
        let from = currentData.dir + "\\" +currentData.fileName;
        console.log("откуда", currentData.dir);
        let where =  currentData.where + "\\" +currentData.fileName;
        console.log("куда", where);
        console.log("что", from);
        
        fs.copySync(from, where);

        if(currentData.sizeOrType === "<папка>"){
            deleteFolderRecursive(currentData.dir + "\\" + currentData.fileName);
        }else{
            fs.unlinkSync(currentData.dir + "\\" + currentData.fileName);
        }                      
        foo(currentData.dir, pathToFile1);
        foo(currentData.where, pathToFile2); 
        
        let objForRedrowBothWindows = [];
        objForRedrowBothWindows.push(fs.readFileSync(pathToFile1, 'utf8'));
        objForRedrowBothWindows.push(fs.readFileSync(pathToFile2, 'utf8'));
        console.log(objForRedrowBothWindows);
        res.json(objForRedrowBothWindows);
        // res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathToFile1));
        // res.sendFile(path.resolve(pathToFile2));
        
        
    });  
});
```

на сервере данные выглядят так:

```
  '{"table":[{"icon":0,"fileName":"11111","sizeOrType":"<папка>","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T19:38:09.517Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test"},{"icon":1,"fileName":"2222","sizeOrType":"<папка>","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T19:13:32.976Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test"},{"icon":2,"fileName":"444444","sizeOrType":"<папка>","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T19:38:11.001Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test"},{"icon":3,"fileName":"Новая папка","sizeOrType":"<папка>","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T13:05:08.541Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test"},{"icon":4,"fileName":"Новый текстовый документ.txt","sizeOrType":"0 байт","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T12:52:54.356Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test"}]}',
  '{"table":[{"icon":0,"fileName":"33333","sizeOrType":"<папка>","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T19:38:17.428Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test2"},{"icon":1,"fileName":"Новый текстовый документ — копия (2).txt","sizeOrType":"0 байт","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T18:06:55.457Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test2"},{"icon":2,"fileName":"Новый текстовый документ — копия (3).txt","sizeOrType":"0 байт","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T18:06:55.457Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test2"},{"icon":3,"fileName":"Новый текстовый документ — копия.txt","sizeOrType":"0 байт","dateOfChange":"2020-10-04T18:06:55.457Z","dir":"C:\\\\\\\\test2"}]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости сторона клиента получает от сервера не массив из двух объектов, а массив из двух JSON-строк, в которых записаны эти объекты. Решить можно двумя способами:

1. На стороне сервера не превращать каждый отдельный объект в JSON, а собрать их в массив и уже массив преобразовать в JSON. Тогда на клиенте он будет получен как массив объектов.
2. На стороне клиента проверять "если элемент массива строка, то JSON.parse()".